# How to customize a TimePicker widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, material-design, timepicker

[image]

How can you change the Purple selection color, Purple border color, time text color and `Hour` and `Minute` color from the input time picker widget, can't seem to find the properties in `TimePickerThemeData`

Comment: If my answer helped you with the problem specified in your original post, please accept it. If not, provide more detail as to why it does not.

Answer (score 10):

You are able to use states on your theme too! Controlling the styles when making some action (like selected or focused actions).

Here an example:

```
final theme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
  timePickerTheme: TimePickerThemeData(
    backgroundColor: Colors.green.shade200,
    hourMinuteColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
        states.contains(MaterialState.selected)
            ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.2)
            : Colors.orange),
    hourMinuteTextColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
        states.contains(MaterialState.selected)
            ? Colors.pink
            : Colors.deepPurple),
    dialHandColor: Colors.pink.shade800,
    dialBackgroundColor: Colors.purple.withOpacity(0.5),
    dialTextColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) =>
        states.contains(MaterialState.selected)
            ? Colors.green
            : Colors.black),
    entryModeIconColor: Colors.yellow
    ),
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      overline: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
    ),
    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
        style: ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.black),
      foregroundColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.green),
      overlayColor: MaterialStateColor.resolveWith((states) => Colors.pink),
    )));
```

[image] [image] [image]

Answer (score 7):

```
showTimePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: 10, minute: 47),
                  builder: (context, child) {
                    return Theme(
                      data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
                        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                          // change the border color
                          primary: Colors.red,
                          // change the text color
                          onSurface: Colors.purple,
                        ),
                        // button colors 
                        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
                          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                            primary: Colors.green,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      child: child,
                    );
                  },
                );
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to also change the `Hour` and `Minute` text color and day period selection color directly ?

Comment: Some of these `Themes colors`  works hand in hand so it is almost impossible to directly change one without affecting another.

Comment: Would you happen to know how to get the old `showTimePicker` widget without downgrading Flutter?

Comment: I don't think that would be possible without the downgrading option, can you post a screenshot of what color combination you are trying to achieve ?

Comment: No problem, just curious, your answer was enough, thanks again